# Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Tags: javascript

I want to extract an ID from the url, the problem is that I got this error:

> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of
>   undefined"

```
let id_value = window.location.pathname.split('/contracts/create/').pop()
isNaN(id_value) ? this.type = "create" : this.type = "update"
```

If do this into a console.log I get a value, and no error.

Comment: Can use share a test case URL?

Comment: Sure,  /contracts/create/562

Comment: ``console`` window.location.pathname and check you are getting the correct path or not.

Comment: Which browser are you testing this one? Also, can you test what does `console.log( window.location )` returns?

Comment: I found the problem. The problem was deeper, first split triggered the second one, where I had the problem. Thanks for help/time.

Comment: did you messup the window.location.pathname previously? because the pathname is not a readonly property unfortunately

Comment: The code is correct. But I had a second split , where I pass a wrong string. That split was triggered after this .

Comment: did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Can you just answer your question please then and tell us what exactly was wrong tnx

Comment: Can share it with us on how you fix it? @Beusebiu

Comment: @MuhammadWazexr Code from the question is correct, error that I was getting was from another split.

Comment: Ok, I will try at my side first. Thank you